# sqlcmd.exe XML structure

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql, command-line

I have a current issue i'm trying to get around the out of memory issue with my vary large XML query. So I found out that SQLCMD.exe has the fastest output time and does not use SSMS memory. The problem is that my command line is not keeping the standard XML structure. Is there a way with using SQLCMD.exe to keep the XML structure?  `SQLCMD.EXE -S %SERVER% -d %DB% -U %USER% -P %PWD% -Q "exec dbo.sp_LeadingRE_dataSelect"   -o  "D:\Data\DataFeeds\RELO_HomeSearch\FTP_Out\62889_TEST.xml"`
Regards, 
Tdubs

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by keeping the XML structure?  I'm not quite following what you mean in your post.

Comment: OK.  I can't say that I'm all that skilled with parameters for SQLCMD; however, I don't think this would be a function of that tool.  The XML is (hopefully) semantically valid, so in that regard, the structure is fine.  You're wanting to see line breaks, carriage returns, tabs, etc. which isn't part of the semantics.  My suggestion would be to load into a tool like Notepad++ that can reformat the file on the fly.

Comment: well the code is returning a single line output, need it to be stacked and indented like <http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_whatis.asp> the examples here